# Android WebView NullPointerException?

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, webclient

In the code below I keep getting a NullPointerException at the line where I set the WebChromeClient. Why is my WebView null?

```
WebView myWebView;
WebChromeClient chromeClient;
WebViewClient wvClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meanwhileinwv.com/");   

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have three other Activities that do this exact same thing, and no issue on the WebView... I added `loadURL()` its at the end.

Comment: Is R.layout.video_player contains the webView?

Comment: post the stacktrace. @pdt is right in telling that wvClient is not instantiated.

Answer (score 4):

Your WebViewClient wvClient is not instatiated yet when you set it, which may be throwing the nullpointerexception.

Comment: no, I have the exact same code in three other activities, exactly like seen above, but it is not working in this one??

Comment: you may need to check if the other codes have declared wvClient before you set it as the parameter. if that doesn't work, use logs, check to see if the which of these objects are actually null.